# How to log Camunda receiving input request and output response through Tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat, logging, camunda

I have python API that I used in camunda bpmn by using `http-connector` and that is working fine. I need to log API request and response everthing but it's not generating. I added `logback.xml` file in `server/apache-tomcat-9.19.0/lib`. my xml file is.

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <!-- camunda -->
  <logger name="org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.JobEntity" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="org.camunda.bpm.engine.jobexecutor" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="org.camunda.bpm.engine.cmd" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="org.camunda.bpm.engine.externaltask" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="org.camunda" level="info" />



  <!-- common dependencies -->
  <logger name="org.apache.ibatis" level="info" />
  <logger name="javax.activation" level="info" />
  <logger name="org.springframework" level="info" />

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

I tried with file also

```
<appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/logs/file.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

</appender>
```

Suggest here what I need to change or add.